# CSS: how to change "ul" position?

Tags: css

The following code shows a pop up menu.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>position ul</title>
<style type="text/css">

html, body, div, ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
#main {
position:relative;
width:950px;
height:30px;
margin:75px auto 0;/*75px beneath top of page, auto distance from page's right/left   side*/
border:2px solid #8c8b4b;
}
#main li {
width:92px;
height:30px;
float:left;
list-style-type:none;
border:2px solid red;
}
#main li a { text-decoration:none; }
#main li ul li {
width:400px;
border:2px solid #8c8b4b;
height:30px;
}
li.menu1 { background-image:url('images/men1.png'); }
li.menu2 { background-image:url('images/men1.png'); }
.menu2 li a {
color:white;
font-weight:bold;
}
li.menu2 div {
position:absolute;
margin-left:-999em;
padding-top:200px;
}
li.menu2 ul {
top:400px;
list-style:none;
margin:0;
font-size:110%;
}
li.menu2:hover div { margin:0; }
li.menu2:hover ul li { clear:left; }
ul li ul.rounded-corner {
border:2px solid red;
height: 200px;
width:776px;
background-image:url(../banner/bg_to_sitepoint.gif);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
-webkit-border-radius:50px;
-moz-border-radius:50px;
border-radius:50px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="main">
<li class="menu1"><a href="#">menu item1</a></li>
<li class="menu2">menu item2
    <div>
       <ul class="rounded-corner">
     <li><a href="#">submenu2 item1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">submenu2 item2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">submenu2 item3</a></li>
    </ul>
     </div>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

The submenu is consisted of a ul entity reesides inside a div.
I would like to change that ul's position within its' ancestor: a div.
I add: "top:100px;" to "li.menu2 ul" selector and see no impact whatsoever. "left" value is no good as well.
Can anyone explain me please why i cannot make that ul repositioned inside its' div?
How can i make it move to other place within the div?
Attached is a screen shot of the present page which i'd like to change.
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

you can add padding-top: 100px to your CSS

```
li.menu2 ul {
  top:400px;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  font-size:110%;
  padding-top:100px;
}
```

take a look here if that's what you meant (and what I understood) 
http://jsfiddle.net/9NqDd/

Comment: Thanks Bart. Your aid was helpful.

Comment: @deotpit: what was the final solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

give this `div`

```
position:relative;
```

if adding

```
padding-top:100px;
```

won't work try

```
margin-top:100px;
```

instead.